# Navicat mySQL query using variable as part of string?

Tags: mysql

Take for example a query with a simple table insert like so:

```
INSERT into TABLENAME (`column1`, `column2`)
               VALUES ([$param], 'string with parameter [$param]');
```

In user is prompted for the parameter value when executed and runs without error. However, column1's value is fine, but value for column2 does not evaluate the parameter within the quote marks for the string.

I can get it to work correctly by changing value for column2 with:

```
CONCAT('string with parameter ',[$param])
```

Is there a way to specify the value for column2 without the need for a function?

Comment: Using prepared statements, you should prepare the arguments before you execute the query

Comment: You should never be concatenating user input directly into SQL (which leaves you open to SQL Injection), take a look at how to bind variables in to a prepared statement using your application language.. for example PDO in PHP.

Comment: This is not a query via PHP. As mentioned in the title, this is a query in Navicat